# Add quotation mark in CMake string

Tags: cmake, escaping

I am using CMake to create and build my project solution. i am using the following command to add a post build event to copy a .tlb from the local bin to the program bin.

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND xcopy /D /Y "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}LocalBin\\example.tlb" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}ProgramBin\\$<CONFIGURATION>\\")
```

When this adds the command to the project properties , it is added as

xcopy /D /Y LocalBin\example.tlb ProgramBin\Debug\

However this gives me an error. Exited with Code 4.

If i go into the project properties and hack the command line and change it to add " "

xcopy /D /Y "LocalBin\example.tlb " "ProgramBin\Debug\"

It works.

Is there a way i can change the CMake add custom command to include the " " in the actual command line so it will work and there is no need to manually change the project properties.

Comment: You have to escape them. Add `\"`.

Comment: Awesome, Change the command to ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND xcopy /D /Y \"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}LocalBin\\example.tlb" \"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}ProgramBin\\$<CONFIGURATION>\\") and it works, Thank you !!! Been banging my head on this one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the quotation mark inside the string. Escaping is done in CMake with a back slash. So adding a quotation mark to your string, add `\"`.

Quoting the CMake documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-language.7.html#escape-sequences

> A `\` followed by a non-alphanumeric character simply encodes the literal character without interpreting it as syntax

In your case you'll end up with

```
"\"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}LocalBin\\example.tlb\""
```

instead of

```
"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}LocalBin\\example.tlb"
```

Comment: I'm confused, should it be `\""${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}LocalBin\\example.tlb"\"`? `"\"` or `\""`

Answer (score 6):

After struggling with this for some time, I found a workable solution using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)):

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND xcopy /D /Y $<1:"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}LocalBin\\example.tlb"> $<1:"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}ProgramBin\\$<CONFIGURATION>\\">)
```

This is an open [bug in CMake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16321).

Comment: What's the advantage over escaping with `\"`?

Comment: Escaping with \" doesn't work in the command name itself.  CMake literally outputs \"

Comment: Does it help to store the command in a variable, where \" works, and passing it as the command?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either.  I suggest you try it out.  I found a couple other creative solutions in addition to the one I mentioned above.  Not sure why someone downvoted without a comment.

Comment: Probably because your answer does not contain the addition information you gave me. I edited in the link to the CMake issue tracker, it is a known bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this works only for the command arguments, but not for the command itself. This is really no fun when you have to call for example shader compiler that is in the Program Files (path with space in it) and prebuild rule fails. To work around this problem I created batch file on the fly with cmake file(WRITE ...) command and then call this batch file with correctly escaped path to the actual shader compiler I want to execute. In the batch I have a line with %1

Solution for my problem

```
file(WRITE Shaders/compile_shaders.bat "\
%1 /ESolveVMF /Tcs_5_0 /DTGSize_=16 /Fh \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Shaders/GenerateRoughnessMaps.inc\" \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Shaders/GenerateRoughnessMaps.hlsl\"\n\
%1 /ESolveVMFReconstructNormal /Tcs_5_0 /DTGSize_=16 /Fh \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Shaders/GenerateReconstructNormalRoughnessMaps.inc\" \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Shaders/GenerateRoughnessMaps.hlsl\"")

add_custom_command(TARGET ${CURRENT_MODULE_NAME} PRE_BUILD
                  COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}\\Shaders\\compile_shaders.bat" "\"$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\\x86\\fxc.exe\""
                  COMMENT "Compiling shaders")
```

Comment: Might be better to generate the `.bat` file from a template using `configure_file()`.